# tr:inputBox onkeypressed feature only works once

Tags: javascript, jsf, trinidad

What I am trying to do is to enter a number into a tr:inputBox that will cause a tr:commandButton to be clicked when I hit "Enter" over the tr:inputBox. It works if I have my developer tools up in IE9 an infinite number of times but if the developer tools is not up, it will only work once. Why is this being non-determinant in this manner?

```
<tr:panelBox styleClass="roundedPanelPrimary">
                     <trh:rowLayout halign="center">
                        <trh:cellFormat halign="center">                                
                            <tr:inputText styleClass="tabdata" contentStyle="normalContent"
                               id= "acctNumber"
                                label="Account Number"
                                type="enter" 
                                onkeypress=" if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('Search').click()"    
                                value="#{fraudSearch.fraudCustomerReqtUIModelBean.accountNumber}"

                            >

                           </tr:inputText>

                        </trh:cellFormat>

                        <trh:cellFormat halign="left">
                            <tr:commandButton text="Search" id="Search"
                                action="#{fraudSearch.getIBSNotesData}" styleClass="Button"
                                halign="center"

                                >

                                </tr:commandButton>
                        </trh:cellFormat>                           
                    </trh:rowLayout>                        
                </tr:panelBox>
```

Comment: Possibly turning on/off Dev tools switches IE compatibility mode up/down. In lower compatibility mode (5, 6 or even 7) you may encounter random issues up to a fully disfunctional web UI. If you don't have studied IE compatibility mode and how to influence it, this feels non deterministic. Additionally UI functionality may suffer from active security restrictions.

Comment: This application is specifically designed to be used on IE 9 browsers.

Comment: The more importent to assert that IE launches the application in IE9 compatibility mode. Lower modes will lead to unpredicted issues within your application.

Comment: Internet Explorer 9 is able to launch your application as if it was Internet Explorer 8,7,6 or 5. This is what I mean when saying IE9 launches your app in compatibility mode IE8. Before spending hours in try and error searching through your own source code, you must be absolutely sure that IE9 launches your app in IE9 mode. I did not mean to say that your app might be incompatible with IE9.

Comment: And the real crazy thing about it is that if I try to debug it in the browser, it works. If I don't try to debug it. Maybe it'll work once or twice but then it stops listening.

Comment: If it helps, the browser is in IE11, but is running something that must run in IE9.